# "What time...?" or "At what time...?" - what is more grammatically correct?

Tags: prepositions, time, wh-questions

This question may sound silly, but it has been bugging me for years.

If I ask a question about a precise point in time, should I say "What time..." or "At what time..."?

For example,

> At what time does Billy arrive at the swimming pool?

or

> What time does Billy arrive at the swimming pool?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The initial preposition ***at*** in such contexts is entirely optional, but it usually *wouldn't* be included (although in reality we *usually* use ***when*** rather than *[at] **what time*** anyway :).

OP's specific example happens to include a "location-based" clause based on ***at*** [the swimming pool], but it might be worth looking at two slightly different contexts...

> 1a: *What time does the shop open?*
>    1b: ***At*** what time does the shop open?
>    1c: *What time does the shop open **at**?*

...and...

> 2a: *Where did you come?*
>    2b: ***From*** where did you come?
>    2c: *Where did you come **from**?*

In my opinion, both 'b' versions above are at least *slightly* stilted / awkward. But whereas 1a and 1c carry the same meaning, that's not the case with the second pair. 2a (*without* the preposition ***from***) is effectively asking *where you ended up*, not where you started from (speaker might be asking your final position in a race, for example; *Where did I come [in the marathon]? I did pretty good, actually - I came third, out of 2000 runners*).

The point being that because there's no credible alternative meaning in the first pair that depends on whether the preposition is included or not, it's *entirely* a stylistic choice (and *on average* we don't bother with unnecessary words). But the second example shows that we *do* include the preposition where it's required to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 3):

As [user070221](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/29952) notes, both sentences are commonly used in American English.  In some formal speech and writing, "At what time" is more acceptable than "When" or "What time", especially when "a precise point in time" is being requested.

I am an American who grew up in a town with many native speakers of Spanish.  To my ear, both examples in the original post sound like overly literal translations of *"¿A qué hora?"*  To my ear, "When" is a more natural way of saying this in English:

> When does Billy arrive at the swimming pool?

Answer (score 2):

Both the sentences are correct and mean the same thing. **what time** is just a shorter form of **at what time**

Answer (score 0):

But can I use "when" in sentence like this?

> *When should I book a meeting room for tomorrow meeting?*

or

> *What time should I book a meeting room for for tomorrow meeting?*

"When" changes the meaning of sentence. So I cannot use "when" in this case.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).